# Date Parsing with Timezone AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetime-format

In have this line in my code.

```
<span> {{messages.created_time}}</span>
```

This is the ouput

```
2017-04-29T12:46:49+0000
```

However, I would like the ouput to be :

```
n minutes ago // if less than one hour following the user timezone

22:46 // if more or equal than one hour following the user timezone

SUN AT 22:46 // if more or equal than a day following the user timezone

APRIL 2 AT 22:46 // if more or equal than a week following the user timezone
```

I am using angular js.
Thanks

Comment: you'll have to write a filter that calculates the different possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simply done by using [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs). Just use angular filter and apply your custom logic.

```
<span> {{messages.created_time | filterfn}}</span>   

function filterfn(time){
  // all custom logic for span text creation
  return $moment(time);
}
```